# UnresolvedException: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object when using DataSet constructed from Seq.empty (since Spark 2.3.0)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following snippet works fine in Spark 2.2.1 but gives a rather cryptic runtime exception in Spark 2.3.0:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class X(xid: Long, yid: Int)
case class Y(yid: Int, zid: Long)
case class Z(zid: Long, b: Boolean)

val xs = Seq(X(1L, 10)).toDS()
val ys = Seq(Y(10, 100L)).toDS()
val zs = Seq.empty[Z].toDS()

val j = xs
  .join(ys, "yid")
  .join(zs, Seq("zid"), "left")
  .withColumn("BAM", when('b, "B").otherwise("NB"))

j.show()
```

In Spark 2.2.1 it prints to the console

```
+---+---+---+----+---+
|zid|yid|xid|   b|BAM|
+---+---+---+----+---+
|100| 10|  1|null| NB|
+---+---+---+----+---+
```

In Spark 2.3.0 it results in:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: 'BAM
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute.dataType(unresolved.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fromAttributes$1.apply(StructType.scala:435)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fromAttributes$1.apply(StructType.scala:435)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$.fromAttributes(StructType.scala:435)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.schema$lzycompute(QueryPlan.scala:157)
  ...
```

The culprit really seems to be `Dataset` being created from an empty `Seq[Z]`. When you change that to something that will also result in an empty `Dataset[Z]` it works as in Spark 2.2.1, e.g.

```
val zs = Seq(Z(10L, true)).toDS().filter('zid === 999L)
```

In the migration guide from 2.2 to 2.3 is mentioned:

> Since Spark 2.3, the Join/Filter’s deterministic predicates that are after the first non-deterministic predicates are also pushed down/through the child operators, if possible. In prior Spark versions, these filters are not eligible for predicate pushdown.

Is this related, or a (known) bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I jumps in, even in the most trivial cases in 2.3 effectively making it completely unusable :( Funny thing, it can be sometimes resolved by using `Strings` in place of `Columns`.

Comment: A more complex case but also when joining with a DataSet constructed from a Seq.empty gave me an error/warning:

    ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 113, Column 35: Not a boolean expression
    WARN WholeStageCodegenExec: Whole-stage codegen disabled for plan (id=1):

Also resolved by using a similar trick.

Answer (score 2):

@user9613318 there is a [bug create by the OP](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23959) but it is closed as "Cannot Reproduce" because the dev says that

> I am not able to reproduce on current master. This must have been fixed.

but there is no reference to another underlying issue so it might remain a mystery.

Comment: Mystery is not very comforting, but resolved is better than nothing. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: So we wait a few months for Spark 2.3.1

Comment: @SamDeBacker, you can also try to create a build from current master but who knows what other bugs are there.

Comment: Well for those who are using stable releases this problem hasn't been resolved. Meanwhile we are forced to stick with 2.2

Comment: @SamDeBacker master is on 2.4, this hasn't been solved in 2.3.1

Comment: It is fixed in 2.3.2 (and later)

Answer (score 2):

I have worked this around on 2.3.0 by issuing `someEmptyDataset.cache()` right after the empty `Dataset` was created. OP's example didn't fail anymore like that (with `zs.cache()`), also the actual problem at work went away with this trick.

(As a side note, OP-s code doesn't fail for me on Spark 2.3.2 run locally. Though I don't see the related fix in 2.3.2 change log, so it's maybe due to some other differences in the environment...)